# create user specific redirect after login react js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, reactjs, mongodb

I am new in React js. I am creating dashboard.There are two role Admin and user.Admin can see more side menus/functionality in dashboard in comparison to user.I have set the flag in Mongodb according to user or Admin role.Now how can we redirect after login according to role So that admin may see more side menu in comparison to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you are managing user sessions. If you are managing them in a traditional flow where your server manages authentication, you would return a redirect response from your server in response to a successful authentication request. If you are doing some sort of oauth flow you will need to configure the oauth client with the proper redirect uri.